# Not able to convert from RDD to Dataset successfully at runtime

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run this small Spark program. Spark Version 2.1.1

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((2012, "Tesla", "S"), (1997, "Ford", "E350"), (2015, "Chevy", "Volt")))
    import spark.implicits._
    val carDetails: Dataset[CarDetails] = spark.createDataset(rdd).as[CarDetails] // Error Line
    carDetails.map(car => {
      val name = if (car.name == "Tesla") "S" else car.name
      CarDetails(car.year, name, car.model)
    }).collect().foreach(print)
```

It is throwing error on this line:

```scala
val carDetails: Dataset[CarDetails] = spark.createDataset(rdd).as[CarDetails] 

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`year`' given input columns: [_1, _2, _3];
```

There is no compilation error!

I tried by doing many changes like to use List instead of RDD. Also, tried to first convert to DS and then to `as[CarDetails]`, but didn't work. Now I am clueless.

Why is it taking the columns as `_1`, `_2` and `_3` when I have already given the case class

```scala
case class CarDetails(year: Int, name: String, model: String)
```

I tried to change from Int to Long for year in case class. It still did not work.

**Edit:**

I changed this line after referring the probable duplicate question and it worked.

```scala
val carDetails: Dataset[CarDetails] = spark.createDataset(rdd)
    .withColumnRenamed("_1","year")
    .withColumnRenamed("_2","name")
    .withColumnRenamed("_3","model")
        .as[CarDetails]
```

But, I am still not clear as to why I need to rename the columns even after explicitly mapping to a case class.

Comment: No, I tried to change to Long from Int. It still did not work.

Comment: Please read the full answer: _To answer your 2nd question, you need to name the columns correctly before the conversion to Person will work_. Exactly as you observed - `DataFrame` you are trying to convert has names `_1`, `_2`, `_3`, while Spark expects `year`, `name`, `model`. If it is not explicit enough: `spark.createDataset(rdd).toDF("year", "name", "model").as[CarDetails]`

Comment: It worked after changing `val carDetails: Dataset[CarDetails] = spark.createDataset(rdd)
    .withColumnRenamed("_1","year")
    .withColumnRenamed("_2","name")
    .withColumnRenamed("_3","model")
        .as[CarDetails]`. But, when I am explicitly creating a Dataset and also providing the case class, then why am I needed to rename the columns!

Comment: Dataset should automatically map the name of the case class variables with the values in the dataset. I am still missing the link here.

Comment: It should not\. `as` method matches names, types and hierarchy, not exact structure.

Answer (score 1):

The rules of `as` conversion are explained in detail in [the API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@as[U](implicitevidence$2:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[U]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[U]):

> The method used to map columns depend on the type of U:
>
> - When U is a class, fields for the class will be mapped to columns of the same name (case sensitivity is determined by spark.sql.caseSensitive).
> - When U is a tuple, the columns will be mapped by ordinal (i.e. the first column will be assigned to _1).
> - When U is a primitive type (i.e. String, Int, etc), then the first column of the DataFrame will be used.
>
> If the schema of the Dataset does not match the desired U type, you can use select along with alias or as to rearrange or rename as required.

To explain this with code. Conversion from case class to `Tuple*` is valid (fields are matched structurally):

```scala
Seq(CarDetails(2012, "Tesla", "S")).toDF.as[(Int, String, String)]
```

but conversion from `Tuple*` to arbitrary case class is not (fields are matched by name). You have to rename fields first (ditto):

```scala
Seq((2012, "Tesla", "S")).toDF("year", "name", "model").as[CarDetails]
```

It has quite interesting practical implications:

- `Tuple` typed object cannot contain extraneous fields:

  ```scala
  case class CarDetailsWithColor(
     year: Int, name: String, model: String, color: String)

  Seq(
    CarDetailsWithColor(2012, "Tesla", "S", "red")
  ).toDF.as[(Int, String, String)]

  // org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Try to map struct<year:int,name:string,model:string,color:string> to Tuple3, but failed as the number of fields does not line up.;
  ```
- While case class typed `Dataset` can:

  ```scala
  Seq(
    (2012, "Tesla", "S", "red")
  ).toDF("year", "name", "model", "color").as[CarDetails]
  ```

Of course, starting with case class typed variant would save you all the trouble:

```scala
sc.parallelize(Seq(CarDetails(2012, "Tesla", "S"))).toDS
```